# execute javascript after documentLibrary is fully loaded alfresco

Tags: alfresco-share

I want to trigger a javascript function after all the documents in the document library are loaded.

I have coded a custom renderer for document library to display custom text for document library. When all the contents of the document library are loaded, I want to execute a javascript on the custom text.

I tried the below code in custom javascript file added as dependency and it does not work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

myjsfunction();

}
```

Comment: How did you add your JS as dependency?

Comment: I added the below dependency in share-config-custom.xml
As a temporary measure, I have used the window.timeout of javascript to trigger the method after a predefined time interval.
<code>

<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="DocLibCustom">
 <dependencies>
  <js src="/kfshrc/customizations/components/js/jquery-1.6.2-min.js"/>
  <js src="/kfshrc/customizations/components/js/nodeType_renderer-min.js"/>
  <js src="/kfshrc/customizations/components/js/lync-min.js"/>
 </dependencies>
</config>

</code>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using a window.setInterval to call cutom javascript function after a predefined time